# Switch Statement in Kendo Template

Tags: templates, switch-statement, kendo-ui

Im using **Kendo Template** and I was able to create a conditional statement (IF statement) as stated on the documentaion.
Here's my code.

```
#if ((item.ControlType) == "tbx"){#
   @(Html.Kendo().AutoComplete()
   .Name("#=ctrlid#")
   .ToClientTemplate())
#}#
```

This works fine.

But what I'd like to have is a **Switch Case**  Statement. I've tried this but it doesn't work. It says "Invalid Template".

```
# switch (item.ControlType) {#
  # case "tbx": #
     @(Html.Kendo().AutoComplete()
       .Name("#=ctrlid#")
       .ToClientTemplate())
  # break; #
  # }#
```

Am I missing something? Or is it just impossible for Kendo Template to interpret Switch Case Statements? (about the latter, I dont think so..I'm definitely missing something)

Can anyone help me please? Thanks!^^

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I check your case and I found the reason for the error. Basically to keep the JavaScript valid you will have to use only one pair of # symbols surounding the switch statement and the first case statement.

e.g.

instead of:

```
# switch (item.ControlType) {#
# case "tbx": #
```

use:

```
# switch (item.ControlType) {
  case "tbx": #
```

To demonstrate it , here is a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/orawuw/2/edit). Basically there should not be problems if you combine the switch with some widget generated by the MVC wrappers. If there is, let me know.